Drainage: Gutter drains good enough for a DWV system?
Moved into a house and trying to figure out the drainage situation, the top bathroom and kitchen both need water traps as a smell comes up from them. There is an extension to the lower bathroom where the drain line goes down (internally) and the drain is in a sealed unit, so I cannot be sure if there is an air vent or a valve at the top - since we get flies I assume its a vent or a leak.
Though I will need to investigate the sealed unit at some point I was wondering does there have to be a vent at the top, or will the gutter drains be good enough? If I install the traps could it create a pressure issue since the gutter drains are on the ground level?
Thanks in advance for all advice!


Actual pictures from under these fixtures and whatever it is in the boxes labeled "___ sealed" would be very helpful. In my mind "sealed" means that water from the top bathroom is hitting this "seal" and stopping, thus you get no drainage and you've got a flood. That doesn't seem to be the case, so your use of "seal" and mine are quite different. A picture would help clarify.

What country are you in.  In many areas the waste water does not dump into the storm water system.
